# MacOS Storyboards - structure with image and dozens of buttons underneath

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard, nsview

As the header says, I am attempting to have a View that will allow an Image button on top as an entire row, and then a row of dozens of buttons underneath.

There are all these nice sounding views (collection view, table view, grid view, etc), but Xcode does not allow me to drag NSButton's, etc onto them using the plus button in the top right of the photo below. How else to add them?

At the moment, I created a collection view which seems perfectly suited. However, I have no idea how to add elements to the view, such as my image button (NS Button) or the row of buttons.

[image]

I have also connected the collection view to a cocoa class:
[image]

Comment: *…but none of them support drag and drop*. No, all of them support drag and drop but not out of the box. You have to implement the appropriate delegate methods.

Comment: Are you saying if I implement a function in my keyboardView class I will be able to drag an NSButton class onto my collection view? What is this function?
I am very new to this field and finding it hard to find resources - what little there is is devoted to iOS and UIKit.

Comment: I may have been unclear, edited. I meant Xcode does not allow me to drag and drop new NS elements into the Collection View, so I do not know how else to add them.

Comment: Now I understand, you have to drag the items in the storyboard into the view. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1047-advanced-collection-views-in-os-x-tutorial) is a tutorial about NSCollectioView.